# Session storage getting wiped

Tags: javascript, android, session

My session variables are getting wiped on my mobile browser when I view another app without quitting chrome and come back. Chrome reloads or something and the variables are gone. Is there a way to overcome this?

To be clear...when switching between tabs and refreshing the page the session Storage works fine.

To debug, I took out all lines that updated session Storage, thinking somewhere the page got cleared and session got updated with empty variables. I replaced those with a button to set session Storage, same behavior.

```
function updateSessionStorage(){
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
    var titleHTML = document.getElementById('StoryTitle').innerHTML;
    var storyHTML = document.getElementById('LogBook').innerHTML;
    var charHTML = document.getElementById('charSheet').innerHTML;
    var notesHTML = document.getElementById('myNotes').innerHTML;
   sessionStorage.setItem("title", titleHTML);
   sessionStorage.setItem("story", storyHTML);
   sessionStorage.setItem("character", charHTML);
   sessionStorage.setItem("notes", notesHTML);
   }
}

function reloadSessionStorage(){
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
    document.getElementById('StoryTitle').innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("title");
    document.getElementById('LogBook').innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("story"); 
    document.getElementById('charSheet').innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("character"); 
    document.getElementById('myNotes').innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("notes");
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('saveAlert') == 'true') 
closeNotice('abilityAlert');     
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('saveCharCreateAlert') == 'true') 
showCharCreateAlert()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Are you the only user? If so maybe the application the session is associated with closes because there's no current users? Also maybe it's a timing issue? Are you away for a while and possibly have a session timeout period set?

Comment: I currently am the only user, it's a local file on my phone. Not away for more than maybe a minute. It is like Android is closing chrome to maximize memory and then reloading it making it seem like I closed the tab or browser and releasing session variables.